# Cipher AES key with RSA

Tags: python, aes, rsa

I have 2 files, one has the RSA public key, and the other one is the AES key. I need to cipher the AES key with RSA.

publickey.pem

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- rest of key -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

key.pem (contains the AES key)

> "llave":
> "b'\xaa\xbd[\x91\x82|\xc6r\x05\xa1\xc2\x13\xca\xb14U'",
> "iv": "pvGatTFSKrWwfKOrZdPzXw=="

I got the part of the file that contains the AES key (llave) and then I ciphered it with RSA. The only problem is that the ciphered key length is 256 bytes.

```
import json
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
def cipher_keyaes():
    with open('publickey.pem', 'rb') as f:
        with open('key.pem', 'rb') as f1:
            data = f.read().decode('utf-8')

            file = json.load(f1)
            print(file)
            key = file['llave']
            key_rsa = RSA.import_key(data)
            cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key_rsa)

            cipher_key = cipher.encrypt(key.encode('utf8'))
            print(cipher_key)
            key = AES.new(cipher_key, AES.MODE_CBC)

            f.close()
```

Is there a way to just get the cipher_key of 16 bytes length?

Comment: With RSA, the ciphertext size is essentially the size of the modulus of the public key. A 16-byte public key would have little security since numbers of that size can be factored

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: AES only exists on 128,196 or 256 bits and the least is strongly recommended. John is also Tellier that this algorithm relies on the hardness to factorize big numbers into prime but due to current CPU, 16 bits is easy so it would not protect anything.

Answer (score 3):

No, a ciphertext size of 16 bytes is next to impossible using asymmetric cryptography.

About the best you can do is about 32 bytes for an ECC public key, which you can then use for IES encryption, which is basically DH key agreement, followed by a key derivation mechanism to derive an AES key.

For AES, the result of the *modular* exponentiation is about the size of the modulus used within RSA (and, for standardized modes, it is usually exactly the size of the modulus, up to the next byte boundary). Hence I can see from the wrapped AES key size of 256 bytes that you are using an RSA modulus of 8 x 256 = 2048 bits (and, as the modulus defines the key size, a key size of 2048 as well).

---

One of the reasons why we use hybrid cryptography, i.e. asymmetric cryptography such as RSA + symmetric cryptography is that asymmetric cryptography adds significant data overhead. This overhead is usually not such a problem for smaller messages or indeed single AES keys, but for larger messages it quickly does become an issue.